# TWIG/SYMFONY2 - The filter "date_modify" does not exist

Tags: php, date, symfony, twig

I am trying to manipulate a date in my index.html.twig with something like:

```
{{ myDate | date_modify("+3 day") | date('Y-m-d') }}
```

and get the error:

> The filter "date_modify" does not exist in
>   XXX:YYY:index.html.twig at line 723

I am using Symfony 2.0.16, and the Date used is working so far.

What could be the reason for the filter not being present in the TWIG Library?

> (Twig_Error_Syntax: The filter "date_modify" does not exist in
>   "XXX:YYY:index.html.twig" at line 723 (uncaught exception) at
>   /.../.../.../.../.../.../vendor/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter.php
>   line 29)

Comment: Which twig version you are using?

Comment: Just found out, it was 1.8.2 .. I wasn´t able to find it first, so I assumed it´s the same as the Symfony Version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New in version 1.9.0: The date_modify filter has been added in Twig 1.9.0.

Probably you have an old version

Answer (score 0):

Create your twig extension. In your bundle, create `Twig/Extension/XXXExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YourBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class XXXExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container; 
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array('date_modify' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'dateModify', array('is_safe' => array('html'))));
    }

    public function dateModify($rangeDate)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Here's a link to the associated Symfony docs about creating your own extension, if anyone needs more info on this approach: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html